# Camera moving on X axis but not Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, transform, mouse

I have a script so the `Main Camera` will move on the `x` axis. This works just fine. Then I had a different scene where I wanted the camera to move on both `x` and `y` axis following the mouse. So I made a new script and my code looks something like this

```
transform.position = newvector3.Movetowards(
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse X") * speed * Time.DeltaTime, 
        0f,  
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse Y")  * speed* Time.DeltaTime
);
```

It moves on the `x` axis fine but not at all on the `y` axis. Does anyone know why?

Comment: you are passing `0f` to the `y`component of the vector and the Y movement to the `z` component of the vector. Is this intended?

Comment: I thought the 0f there was just to fill in the third space required to have in a Vector 3. I'm still new to this, does the 0f need to be something else?

Comment: Try switching places between the second and third vector components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
transform.position = newvector3.Movetowards(
    Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse X") * speed * Time.DeltaTime,  
    Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse Y")  * speed* Time.DeltaTime,
    0f
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think MoveTowards is not the best way to change position if you don't know which is the target point. You should simply add an increment to your coordinates:

```
transform.position += new Vector3(
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse X") * speed * Time.DeltaTime, 
        0f,  
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse Y")  * speed* Time.DeltaTime
);
```

Please correct me if position can't be incremented.
This should move your object on X and Z axis.

Comment: Mathf.Clamp needs a float value to limit between a minimum and a maximum, you should normalize your move direction and then multiply it by the magnitude value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do not  sure if this will work but give it a try

```
public float speed;
    private void Update()
    {

        Vector3 someVector3;


        someVector3.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse x") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        someVector3.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        someVector3.z = 0;

        transform.position += someVector3;
    }
}
```